# AWS IAM bucket permissions access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Has anyone encountered the situation when I use manage policies on a user, It works but when I use inline policy it says access denied. I am giving Read access to a bucket for IAM user that is it can only access that bucket.

Manage Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Inline Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried this

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "S3Permissions",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "it does not work"? Its not very specific. Any errors?

Comment: The problem I get is Access denied

Comment: Access deny where? For using AWS Console more permissions are required. For programmatic access your last policy should be fine.

Comment: Access denied in the dashboard for the IAM user in the dashboard. The user can access all buckets with the "manage policy Amazons3ReadonlyAccess" but when I remove it and attach inline policy with same policy or different policy, the user is denied access to the all buckets or the specified folder

Answer (score 2):

Your last policy should be fine for **direct access** to the bucket as explained in:

- [How can I grant a user Amazon S3 console access to only a certain bucket or folder?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/)

For **console access**, additional permissions are required, as shown in:

- [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Specifically the policy should like like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`Amazons3ReadonlyAccess` has all the above permissions, your inline policy does not.